# Context with generic typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-tsx, global-state

I am in the process of creating a generic component in **typescript** that we call `GenericComponent` for a library.

I want to achieve the following behavior from my library :

```
function GenericComponent<T>(props: GenericComponentProps<T>) {
  // ...
  return (
    <GenericContext.Provider value={...}>
      {/* ... */}
    </GenericContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

However, the issue is that **the data provided in my context depends on the generic type of the component where it's being provided**, `T`. So, how can I create my context? Because I can't do:

```
const GenericContext = createContext<GenericContextType<T>>(...)
```

I tried to create my context within the component, but I don't know if it's a best approach.

After development, using `GenericComponent` should looks like this :

```
type TheTypeT = ...

function App() {
   // a state or something that we pass to the component
   const [theTypeT, setTheTypeT] = useState<TheTypeT>(...);

   return (
      <GenericComponent 
          theTypeT={theTypeT}
      />
   );
}
```

But I don't know where in my library I could create my context that depend on the type of `theTypeT`

Comment: Create a wrapper around the `createContext` with generics, which returns this `GenericComponent` to wrap some children and a hook `useGenericComponent` that'll provide the state value from the context.

Comment: @0xts So where I call createContext ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I present the approach I take, it's pretty clean, imho. Here's a [Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/create-context-react-hook-crpymd) for all the code, down below, each file is linked individually as well.

First, I create a wrapper around the react's `createContext` like this -

[`src/hooks/create-context.ts`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/create-context-react-hook-crpymd?file=%2Fsrc%2Fhooks%2Fcreate-context.ts)

```ts
import { createContext as reactCreateContext, useContext as reactUseContext } from "react";

export default function createContext<T extends Record<string,unknown>>() {
    const context = reactCreateContext<T | undefined>(undefined);

    const useContext = (): T => {
        const c = reactUseContext(context);

        if (c === undefined) {
            throw new Error("No Context Found: make sure to use the hook inside the Context Provider children");
        }
        return c;
    }

    return [useContext, context.Provider] as const;

}
```

Then, to make the typings for different context types available, without having to import them manually, create a file [`index.d.ts`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/create-context-react-hook-crpymd?file=%2Findex.d.ts) at project root level to house typings, and add your types here to use from, I'm showing a simple counter example using this -

```ts
declare namespace Counter {
    export type State = { counter: number };
    export type Action = { type: "INC_COUNTER" | "DEC_COUNTER" | "RESET_COUNTER", payload: number };
    export type Context = {
        counterState: State;
        counterDispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>
    }
}
```

To make the types from `index.d.ts` available in all the places, edit [`tsconfig.json`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/create-context-react-hook-crpymd?file=%2Ftsconfig.json) to add the `./index.d.ts` path in the `include` field -

```ts
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src", "./index.d.ts"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, on to creating our counter context, create a file [`src/hooks/counter-context.tsx`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/create-context-react-hook-crpymd?file=%2Fsrc%2Fhooks%2Fcounter-context.tsx) and use the `createContext` hook created to create a counter context -

```ts
import { useReducer } from "react";
import createContext from "./create-context";

const reducer = (state: Counter.State, action: Counter.Action): Counter.State => {
    const copy = { ...state }
    switch (action.type) {
        case "DEC_COUNTER":
            copy.counter -= action.payload;
            return copy;
        case "INC_COUNTER":
            copy.counter += action.payload;
            return copy;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const initialState: Counter.State = { counter: 0 };

const [_useCounterContext, CounterContextProvider] = createContext<Counter.Context>();

export const useCounterContext = _useCounterContext;

export function CounterContext ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    return <CounterContextProvider value={{ counterState: state, counterDispatch: dispatch }}>
                {children}
            </CounterContextProvider>
}
```

From this file, we export the `useCounterContext` hook provided by the `createContext` and the `CounterContext` component that provides access to the context.

After that, use `CounterContext` above the component, whose children will be using the context. In my case, I use the context in [`src/App.tsx`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/create-context-react-hook-crpymd?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx), so we add the `CounterContext` in [`src/main.tsx`](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/create-context-react-hook-crpymd?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.tsx), which uses `<App />` component as child -

```ts
// src/main.tsx file

import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import { CounterContext } from "./hooks/counter-context";


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <CounterContext>
      <App />
    </CounterContext>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And then at last, we use the context in any child of the `<App />` component, or the `<App />` component itself, like so -

```ts
// src/App.tsx file

import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useCounterContext } from "./hooks/counter-context";

function App() {
  const {counterState: { counter }, counterDispatch } = useCounterContext();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <a href="https://reactjs.org" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <img src="/vite.svg" className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>React + Vite</h1>
      <div className="card">
      <h2>Count: {counter}</h2>
      <div style={{display: "flex", gap: "1rem"}}>
        <button onClick={() => {counterDispatch({type: "INC_COUNTER", payload: 1})}}>Increment</button>
        <button onClick={() => {counterDispatch({type: "DEC_COUNTER", payload: 1})}}>Decrement</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking an interest in this issue @0xts. I know this approach where we create a factory function that generate our hooks and others, but as I said I'm creating a generic component in typescript **for a library**. Thus, I want to do it under the wood, but I don't know the place where I need to create my context, because here you define the type and context by your own, me I want to have this approach : user of my library use my component, so he never need to create it's own context or hooks from the type that he create.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with more information. How about an HOC? With that you'll still be doing the same thing I explained in my answer, but with an HOC.

Comment: Okay I'll explore that way